# Iniciando uma Array de um atributo privado em outra classe

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade

Estou fazendo uns exercícios e me deparei com um problema, segue parte do meu código:

```
class Empresa{
public String nome;
public String cnpj;
private Funcionario[] empregados;
public String rua;
public String bairro;
public int livre = 0;

public Funcionario getFuncionario(int posicao){
    return this.empregados[posicao];
}
public Funcionario getEmpregados(){
    return this.empregados = empregados;
}
//resto da classe
//....
//Segunda classe
//
class EmpresaTeste{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
    empresa.empregados = new Funcionario[10];
    Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();
    f1.nome = "Primeiro funcionario";
    f1.departamento = "Faxina";
    f1.setSalario(1000);
    f1.setRg("37263857634");
    f1.data = new Data();
    f1.data.preencheData(12, 11, 2011);
    empresa.adiciona(f1);
    //...
    if(empresa.contem(empresa.getFuncionario(2))){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Ok");
    }else{
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Funcionario não encontrado");
    }
}}
```

Pois é, na quarta linha da `EmpresaTeste` estou iniciando o *array* empregados da classe `Empresa`, mas o atributo está como `private`, já no fim da classe `EmpresaTeste` tenho um `if` que eu consegui ter acesso ao atributo empregados através do `get`. Como faço para ter acesso quando tiver que iniciar uma *array*?

Se eu fizer

```
empresa.getEmpregados = new Funcionario[10];
```

ele me retornará um erro.

Comment: Cada classe deve tratar da sua própria inicialização. Se queres criar uma empresa com 10 empregados, a maneira idiomática de o fazer é através do constructor: `new Empresa(10)`, ou `new Empresa(new Funcionario[10])`.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu disse, estou seguindo os exercícios.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Provavelmente o que você quer seria isto:

```
public void setEmpregados(Funcionario[] empregados) {
    this.empregados = empregados;
}
```

Mas como vai precisar sempre criar um *array* desse tipo, pode simplificar e mandar só o tamanho que deseja.

```
public void setEmpregados(int tamanho) {
    this.empregados = new Funcionario[tamanho];
}
```

Dá até para manter as duas versões.

Aí seu `get` ficaria assim:

```
public Funcionario getEmpregados(){
    return this.empregados;
}
```

A forma mais correta seria inicializar o *array* em um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Você poderia continuar tendo esses métodos `set`, até porque pode querer mudar o valor do *array* como um todo. Se o código deixar como opção a inicialização do *array*, erros inesperados poderão acontecer.

```
public Empresa(int tamanho) {
    this(new Funcionario[tamanho]);
}

public Empresa(Funcionario[] empregados) {
    this.empregados = empregados;
}
```

Eu aconselharia mudar o *array* por um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Eu sei que pode fugir um pouco do objetivo mas permitiria que o código fosse melhorado não exigindo que o número de empregados fosse dinâmico. E na prática esta flexibilidade é desejável.

Com o *array*, se quiser mudar o número de empregados, tem que pegá-lo, criar um outro *array* com o novo tamanho, copiar os dados necessários do antigo para o novo e colocar na classe novamente. Com uma lista é possível fazer isto internamente na classe. E permitiria uma inicialização garantida:

```
private ArrayList<Funcionario> empregados = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/InitInClass.java).

Assim dispensa o construtor e um `set`. Claro que ainda precisaria ter um método para adicionar e remover empregados. Mas isto também é necessário usando usa um *array*. Ainda precisaria de tratamentos e validações para acessar os dados deste campo, assim como se fosse *array*, mas é uma solução mais adequada.

Essa classe está mal estruturada. Seria bom repensar algumas coisas nela.

[Não sou fã do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Mal estruturada como, amigo? Eu ainda tenho classe funcionario e data... que tem alguns atributos que foram usados na classe EmpresaTeste..

Comment: Tem várias coisas mas o fato de ter quase tudo público é uma delas. Fica pior escolher uma só propriedade para ser privada. É ruim pelo fato de não ter construtores. Não ter a infraestrutura para lidar o *array*. Ter método que não faz nada útil. Ter nomenclaturas inconsistentes.

Comment: Certo, fui seguindo o que estava nos exercícios do Alura, exceto a parte de definir os modificadores de acesso, vou melhorar o que você disse. Obrigado!

Comment: Talvez o problema seja a qualidade do curso então.

Answer (score 2):

Cada classe deve tratar da sua própria inicialização.

Se queres criar uma empresa com 10 empregados, a maneira idiomática de o fazer é através do constructor: `new Empresa(10)`, ou `new Empresa(new Funcionario[10])`.

```
public class Empresa {
  public Empresa(int nFuncionarios) {
    this(new Funcionario[nFuncionarios]);
  }

  public Empresa(Funcionario[] funcs) {
    this.funcionarios = funcs;
  }
}
```

Os métodos fornecidos pela classe `Empresa` devem permitir apenas a actualização/mutação do seu estado (ex: adicionar funcionários, remover funcionários, promover funcionários, etc).

Um aparte: a implementação do método `getEmpregados` deveria ser `return this.empregados`, em vez de `return this.empregados = empregados`.

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua resposta, amigo! o erro da implementação do getEmpregado foi corrigido.

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua resposta, amigo! o erro da implementação do getEmpregado foi corrigido. Acho que não consegui ser bem claro na pergunta, mas consegui resolver a minha dúvida assim : empresa.setEmpregados(new Funcionario[10]); (erro bobo).